# Batch file for adding multiple tags in xml

Tags: xml, windows, batch-file

Here is my input file of XML, I need to add some more tags after a particular tag using bat script of Windows.I need to add these 3 tags:

```
 <add key="Name1" value="Value1"/>
 <add key="Name2" value="Value2"/>
 <add key="Name3" value="Value3"/>
```

inside :

```
<appSettings>
</appSettings>
```

This is the input file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
     <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
      </startup>
     <appSettings>
     </appSettings>
     <runtime>
       <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="true"/>
     </runtime>
     </configuration>
```

And this is the expected output file:

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <configuration>
      <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
      </startup>
      <appSettings>
         <add key="Name1" value="Value1"/>
         <add key="Name2" value="Value2"/>
         <add key="Name3" value="Value3"/>
      </appSettings>
      <runtime>
         <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="true"/>
      </runtime>
     </configuration>
```

How can I do This? Since I'm new to bat scripts.

Comment: You do not want to do this with a batch-file.  Vbscript, Jscript and Powershell have native XML capabilities.  Bat files do not.

Comment: But i need in bat file only,not in powershell